# Construct function from domain and image arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor, functional-programming, racket

I've come across a pretty basic task for functional programming, I can't solve in javascript:

I'm trying wo write a (higher order) function that takes two arrays `domain` and `image` and returns a function. The returned function should return the `n`-th element of the `image` when given that `n`-th element of the domain:

Example:

```
let f = makeFunction([a,b,c],[d,e,f]);
f(a) //returns d
f(b) //returns e
f(c) //returns f
f(x) //any other value returns undefined
```

First I was trying to solve this problem like it's commonly done in functional programming. (Example in Racket)

```
(define makeFunction
    (lambda (domain image)
        (lambda (x)
            (cond
                [(= x (first domain)) (first image)
                [else ((makeFunction (rest domain) (rest image) x)]
            )
        )
    )
)
```

However something like this isn't possible in js, since the Function constructor doesn't create a closure ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)). Therefor my second attempt was to simply stringify the arrays and include them in the function definition (I also included input checking):

```
function makeFunction(domain, image){
    if(new Set(domain).size==domain.length&&domain.length==image.length){
        return new Function("x",`return ${JSON.stringify(image)}[${JSON.stringify(domain)}.indexOf(x)]`);
    }else{
        throw new Error("The lists don't allow the creation of a function, because they either don't have the same length or the domain isn't unique.");
    }
}
```

This function works as long as primitive data types are the only ones the `domain` contains. But as soon as it includes objects, or even cyclic data, I've no idea how to make this function work...

```
//works as expected:
let f = makeFunction([1,2,3,4,"foo"],[4,3,2,1,"bar"]);

//always returns undefined:
let g = makeFunction([{foo:"bar"},{bar:"foo"}],[{bar:"foo"},{foo:"bar"}]);

//returns an error, since JSON.stringify doesn't work on cyclic data:
let cyclicData = {};
cyclicData.self = cyclicData;
let h = makeFunction([cyclicData],["foo"]);
```

Hopefully you can help me with this one :)

Comment: The Function constructor doesn't really have anything to do with it. You can just write a plan function that returns a function, and that *will* create a closure.

Comment: @Pointy But how would I create and return a function inside my makeFunction function without unsing the Function constructor?

Comment: `return function(x) { ... }` — in practice the Function constructor is used *very* rarely.

Comment: And note that object comparisons in JavaScript are always based on object identity. An object that just *looks* the same as another will not compare as equal.

Comment: So it's basically something like `(domain,image) => function(x){return image[domain.indexOf(domain)]};` ?! Ok, that was a lot easier than expected ^^ thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You noticed the pain you experience with `new Function` but you could've constructed a function using the `function` keyword like you did for `makeFunction`.

The following JavaScript function literal syntaxes below create lexicographic closures.<sup>[1]</sup> We'll be using the last syntax because it's closest to Racket

```
function makeFunction (param1, param2, ...) { statement1; statement2; ... }
 
const makeFunction = function (param1, param2, ...) { statement1; statement2; ... }

const makeFunction = (param1, param2, ...) => { statement1; statement2; ... }

const makeFunction = (param1, param2, ...) => expression
```

Your Racket program translates directly into JavaScript so long as we provide the `first` and `rest` functions. Note that `isEmpty` was added so that `makeFunction ([], [])` still works

```js
const isEmpty = (xs = []) =>
  xs.length === 0

const first = (xs = []) =>
  xs [0]

const rest = (xs = []) =>
  xs.slice (1)

const makeFunction = (domain = [], image = []) =>
  x =>
    isEmpty (domain)
      ? undefined
      : x === first (domain)
        ? first (image)
        : makeFunction (rest (domain), rest (image)) (x)

const f =
  makeFunction ([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'd', 'e', 'f' ])

console.log (f ('a')) // d
console.log (f ('b')) // e
console.log (f ('c')) // f
console.log (f ('x')) // undefined
```

Array destructuring assignment and default arguments allow us to see another way we could write our functions

```
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const isEmpty = ([ x = Empty, ...xs ]) =>
  x === Empty

const first = ([ x = Empty, ...xs ]) =>
  x

const rest = ([ x = Empty, ...xs ]) =>
  xs
```

Or we can skip creating intermediate functions `first` and `rest` and use destructuring syntaxes directly in `makeFunction`

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()
  
const makeFunction = ([ key = Empty, ...keys ], [ value = Empty, ...values ]) =>
  x =>
    key === Empty
      ? undefined
      : x === key
        ? value
        : makeFunction (keys, values) (x)

const f =
  makeFunction ([ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'd', 'e', 'f' ])

console.log (f ('a')) // d
console.log (f ('b')) // e
console.log (f ('c')) // f
console.log (f ('x')) // undefined
```

As @user3297291 points out, you should be looking at `Map` as it can look up a key in logarithmic time – compared to linear (slower) time used by `makeFunction`

<sup>[1]</sup> Functions using arrow (`=>`) syntax have also have a lexicographical `this` value

Answer (score 0):

You can return a function that returns a function, this will create a closure for you.

Example:

```
   makeFunction = (domain, image) => ((element) => (image[domain.findIndex(d => d === element)]))
   f = makeFunction([1,2,3,4, 'foo'], [4,3,2,1, 'bar']);
   f(1) // 4
   f(2) // 3
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using javascript's `Map`? Its `get` method is almost what you're trying to implement:

```js
const makeFunction = (domain = [], image = []) => {
  const m = new Map(pairs(domain, image));
  return m.get.bind(m);
};

let a = { foo: "bar" };

let f = makeFunction([1,2,3,4,"foo"],[4,3,2,1,"bar"]);
let g = makeFunction([ a ]);
let h = makeFunction([ a ], [ 1 ]);


console.log(f(1));
console.log(g(a));
console.log(h(a));

// This still won't work though:
console.log(h({ foo: "bar" }));

function pairs([x, ...xs], [y, ...ys], ps = []) {  
  return x && y
    ? pairs(xs, ys, [...ps, [x, y]])
    : ps;
};
```

Its keys however are still checked "by reference". If you want `{ foo: "bar" } == { foo: "bar" }` you'll have to write some custom equality comparer...